# Talk directly from content script to extension? Or do we have to go through background script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Simple question - with regard to Chrome Extensions - is there a way to talk directly from a content script to the extension, or do we have to go through the background script first? Right now, it looks like my content script can only talk to the extension via the background script.

This is what I have:

```
// content script:
let port = chrome.runtime.connect();
port.postMessage({from: 'content-script'});

// background script:
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {

    // msg is from content-script
    // "forward" the message to the extension
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg, function (response) {
      console.log('response from extensions:', response);
    });
  });
});

// extension runtime (what is a good name for it?)
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (msg && msg.refresh === true) {
    window.location.href = msg.url;
  }
});
```

so what's happening, is that in the content script, if I want to send a message to extension, I send the message to background script, which then forwards the message to the extension itself. So like I said, is there a way to communicate directly from the content-script to the extension without going through the background script? How?

Comment: Are you trying to send messages to another extension?
The example shows sending message within the same extension.

Comment: I am just trying to send messages to my own extension / same extension

Comment: Then you have achieved it. The background script is what you call "extension".

Comment: Well, the background script seems to talk with the extension via message passing, so they must be different threads or processes.

Comment: Do you maybe mean popup script when saying "extension"?

Comment: I just mean the difference between the background page/script and the extension itself, there is a difference, some extensions might not even have a background script.

Comment: 'extension' is vague as it is comprised of different parts. Check the [Architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). The background script handles the overall logic of the extension. The content script is the JS part that interacts with the web browser. Then there's the UI Html which serves as the display.